# How to delete an image permanently from the database and folder location when a record is updated or deleted

Tags: php, yii

I am having an issue. I have an image option for my record, but when I update my record or delete the record then it just impact the database tables and the images files are still located in the folder location. I have read about unlink function of php, but don't know how to use it in my case.
Here is my code http://pastebin.com/KQZyAuA0 for the update and delete actions, if anyone knows the answer then kindly share with me.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code here.

Comment: you need to paste the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the code at $model->save() to this,  so before you redirect you check if old images exist in directory, delete them.

```
        $oldThumb = Yii::getPathOfAlias('media') . '/album/optimized/' . $model_old_data->photo;
        $oldOptimized = Yii::getPathOfAlias('media') . '/album/optimized/' . $model_old_data->photo;

        if ($model->save()) {
            if (file_exists($oldThumb)) {
                unlink($oldThumb);
            }
            if (file_exists($oldOptimized)) {
                unlink($oldOptimized);
            }
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
```

Action delete must be changed to,

```
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {
// we only allow deletion via POST request
            $model_old_data = $this->loadModel($id);
            $oldThumb = Yii::getPathOfAlias('media') . '/album/optimized/' . $model_old_data->photo;
            $oldOptimized = Yii::getPathOfAlias('media') . '/album/optimized/' . $model_old_data->photo;

            $model = $this->loadModel($id);
            if ($model->delete()) {
                if (file_exists($oldThumb)) {
                    unlink($oldThumb);
                }
                if (file_exists($oldOptimized)) {
                    unlink($oldOptimized);
                }
            }

// if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
            if (!isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
            }
        } else {
            throw new CHttpException(400, 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
        }
    }
```